# Using C style unsigned char array and bitwise operators in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working on changing some Objective-C Code over to Swift, and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to take care of unsigned char arrays and bitwise operations in this specific instance of code.

Specifically, I'm working on converting the following Objective-C code (which deals with CoreBluetooth) to Swift:

```
unsigned char advertisementBytes[21] = {0};
[self.proximityUUID getUUIDBytes:(unsigned char *)&advertisementBytes];
advertisementBytes[16] = (unsigned char)(self.major >> 8);
advertisementBytes[17] = (unsigned char)(self.major & 255);
```

I've tried the following in Swift:

```
var advertisementBytes: CMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>
self.proximityUUID.getUUIDBytes(advertisementBytes)
advertisementBytes[16] = (CUnsignedChar)(self.major >> 8)
```

The problems I'm running into are that getUUIDBytes in Swift seems to only take a `CMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>` object as an argument, rather than an array of CUnsignedChars, so I have no idea how to do the later bitwise operations on advertisementBytes, as it seems it would need to be an unsignedChar array to do so.

Additionally, `CMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar[21]>` throws an error saying that fixed length arrays are not supported in CMutablePointers in Swift.

Could anyone please advise on potential work-arounds or solutions? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

Mostly this

> C Mutable Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking a CMutablePointer
>   argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - A CMutablePointer value
> - An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type Type,
>     which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - An in-out Type[] value,
>     which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and
>     lifetime-extended for the duration of the call
>
> If you have declared a
>   function like this one:
>
> SWIFT
>
> ```
> func takesAMutablePointer(x: CMutablePointer<Float>) { /*...*/ } You
> ```
>
> can call it in any of the following ways:
>
> SWIFT
>
> ```
> var x: Float = 0.0 
> var p: CMutablePointer<Float> = nil 
> var a: Float[] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] 
> takesAMutablePointer(nil) 
> takesAMutablePointer(p) 
> takesAMutablePointer(&x) 
> takesAMutablePointer(&a)
> ```

So you code becomes

```
var advertisementBytes = CUnsignedChar[]()
self.proximityUUID.getUUIDBytes(&advertisementBytes)
advertisementBytes[16] = CUnsignedChar(self.major >> 8)
```

Comment: Could you include the `Objective-C` versions too?